# Dynamically updating templates in ractive

Tags: ractivejs

I'm trying to use ractivejs to dynamically set a template, based on the example at http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/advanced-configuration. The problem I'm having is that changing the template once (using this.reset) works fine the first time, but not the second - the observer is never called, and the component seems to be 'disassociated' from the main ractive object - for example, data references to elements defined in the parent Ractive object stop displaying the value and just show a blank string.

A small test case is available at http://jsfiddle.net/bbaetz/41n2yvft/4/ but the main script is:

```
var Widget1 = Ractive.extend({
    template : '#widget1-template'
});

var Widget2 = Ractive.extend({
    template: function( data ) {
        return data.template
    },
    init : function() {
        this.observe( 'widgetParams.val', function (newVal, oldVal) {
            if (newVal === oldVal ) { return; }
            var newData = {
                template : 'Reset: {{val}} and {{widgetParams.val}}',
                val : newVal + ' data',
            };
            this.reset(newData);
        }.bind(this), {init: false} );
    },
    data : {
        template : 'A: {{val}}',
        val : 'INIT',
    }
});

var ractive = new Ractive({
    el : 'foo',
    template : '#template',
    components : {
        widget1 : Widget1,
        widget2 : Widget2
    },
    data : {
        widgetParams : {
            val : '12345678',
        },
    },
});
```

with the template:

```
<foo></foo>

<script id='widget1-template' type='text/ractive'>
    <button on-click='set("widgetParams.val","12345")'>set val to 12345</button>
    <button on-click='set("widgetParams.val","54321")'>set val to 54321</button>

    Val is: {{widgetParams.val}}
    <br />
</script>

<script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
    <widget1></widget1>

    <widget2></widget2>
</script>
```

The second widget starts off outputting 'A: INIT' (which is correct). If I click one of the buttons then it changes to 'Reset: 12345 data and 12345' (also right), but if I click on the other button I get 'Reset: 54321 data and ' - this shows that its lost visibility to the other 'widgetParams.val' attribute. After that, the observer is never fired (probably because its observing the attribute its lost access to?)

Is this a bug in ractive, or am I doing something wrong?

(The use-case for this is one component that allows the user to select from a list of accounts, and a second component that will do an ajax call to get data and a template based on the 'type' of account. The second 'widget' will be reused on other contexts, which is why this whole thing isn't just one template by itself/using partials.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to preserve the data, reuse the existing data object in your observer (see http://jsfiddle.net/41n2yvft/6/):

```
this.observe( 'widgetParams.val', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal === oldVal ) { return; }
    this.data.template = 'Reset: {{val}} and {{widgetParams.val}}';
    this.data.val = newVal + ' data';
    this.reset(this.data);
}.bind(this), {init: false} );
```

But in this case, you might just want to update the template without resetting the data (http://jsfiddle.net/41n2yvft/7/):

```
this.observe( 'widgetParams.val', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal === oldVal ) { return; }
    this.set('val', newVal + ' data');
    this.resetTemplate('Reset: {{val}} and {{widgetParams.val}}');
}.bind(this), {init: false} );
```

Probably time to update the docs with some more examples. :)

Comment: I'm actually trying to do both - I want to replace the data and the template (which will come from an ajax call). I noticed that this works if I select 'ractivejs edge', so this seems like a bug that has been fixed

Comment: In the second example, is there a way to update the val and template atomically? The old template might not support the new data model